# using amixer to set audio makes left and right unbalanced

Tags: volume, alsa, pulseaudio, amixer

I am using a Logitech keyboard which has a scroll-bar to set volume, which allow for some nifty macros on Linux. However, using it to set volume with `amixer -q set Master -D pulse 1%+` makes the left/right channels unbalanced.

The image show the left/right channels after being locked, changed volume up and down and then unlocked, to check the individual volumes. Any suggestions as to why this happens and how it can be corrected, as I assume I am doing something wrong.

[image]

for another  controller

[image]

So it happens to all types of sinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  finally found a solution that works. Using `pactl` works wonders!

```bash
pactl set-sink-volume 0 {+1%, -1%}
```